# Send value or string from main.cpp to mainwindow.cpp

Tags: c++, qt

I need a help to send a value from main.cpp to mainwindow.cpp before opening the window.

More or less, the process should be this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    // some code here where I control parameters

    // Here I have some values and/or strings to send to MainWindow

    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Now how can I send them? I don't want to create a file where put these values.

Thanks in advance for the help

## Edit 1

I'm a bit confused:

I try with the last answer to resolve the problem but I think but there is something missing.
This is the code (this is a sample to see if sending data works):

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    MainWindow(QString variable);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->label->setText(variable); //"variable" is not declared. Here I think is the error
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w("Hello"); //undefined reference to MainWindow::MainWindow(QString)
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to send the value? You want to change the state of MainWindow at initialization, right? Why would you not do this via the constructor of MainWindow?

Comment: Because, before open the application, I need to check some file, import some values and then open the mainwindow with that values for use the application.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement public setter functions for your mainwindow and call them from your main.cpp

Let's say you want to have access to the title string and the number of buttons, you can implement these functions in your MainWindow class:

```cpp
public:
    void SetTitle(const QString& p_title);
    void SetNumberOfButtons(int p_num);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... I'm trying to send some values from main to mainwindow before the mainwindow is open, because I need these values for use in function when I press a button or other functions.

Comment: You can still use a setter, no user input will be processed before the event loop is entered (QApplication::exec())

Comment: these ones i mentioned were just example, you can have your own variables in the MainWindow class, let's say `int m_MyIntVar;` and `QString m_MyStringVar;` and have you can either put them among the public fields or you can keep them private and have public setters like `void SetMyIntVar(int i);` and `void SetMyStringVar(const QString& s);`